# Python monkey patching

Tags: python, monkeypatching

I need to monkeypatch requests' Response class (version 1.0.4, current as of this question), to add additional methods.

I have this code:

```
import requests

class Response(requests.models.Response):
    def hmm(self):
        return 'ok'

requests.models.Response = Response

r = requests.get('http://bbc.co.uk')

print r
```

It fails when the original Response calls super() - https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/models.py#L391

I think this is because it gets confused, as I have replaced the class, I feel like I'm doing something silly, any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In [2]: requests.__version__
Out[2]: '1.0.4'

Is this true for you as well? This code used to work for me with an older version of requests

Comment: File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 391, in __init__
    super(Response, self).__init__()
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'd be better off just adding your function directly to the class:

```
def hmm(self):
    return 'ok'
requests.models.Response.hmm = hmm
```

This works just fine:

```
>>> import requests
>>> def hmm(self):
...     return 'ok'
... 
>>> requests.models.Response.hmm = hmm
>>> r = requests.get('http://bbc.co.uk')
>>> print r
<Response [200]>
>>> r.hmm()
'ok'
>>> requests.__version__
'1.0.4'
```

Comment: I know we Pythonistas __hate__ OOP, but how about subclassing?

Comment: @tenfishsticks: You'd still have to replace the `Response` class with that subclass as the `requests` APIs will return instances of that class. For adding a method, it is just simpler to add the method to the existing class.

Answer (score 5):

I don’t think you can monkey-patch that type like that. When importing `requests`, all [these](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/__init__.py) modules are initialized. And as the whole library uses `from xy import Request` over and over, it will have an exact reference to the actual type. And only after that, you replace the Response type within the models module, so only subsequent imports are affected.

Unless you go through all the modules and manually replace their Response reference with your new type, they will still use the original one, making your patch useless.

Instead, you should keep the original type but expand it directly, as Martijn suggested.

Comment: Thank you. I will use inspect.getmembers to grab all methods from my class and assign them to the original class. Slightly less elegant, but will work.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick fix using [`setattr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr), but it's a bit ugly (but semantically equivalent to [@Martijn answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14159081/89391)):

```
def hmm(self):
    return 'OK - %s' % self.status_code

setattr(requests.models.Response, 'hmm', hmm)

r = requests.get('http://bbc.co.uk')
print r.hmm()
# prints 
# OK - 200
```